# Passing C++ function pointers to Fortran subroutine

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters, fortran

I have been trying to debug this code which calls a Fortran subroutine, DLSODE. Two of the parameters of this subroutine are functions, FEX and JEX, which I am passing as function pointers. From what I understand, any of the functions used by a fortran subroutine must have call by reference parameters, as fortran does not accept call by value.

My problem is the error I get seems to indicate I have a discrepancy between the data types I declared in the function declaration of the pointer and the function definition below, and I have not been successful in debugging it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;




extern"C" {void DLSODE_(void (*fex)(int, double, double[], double[]), int *NEQ,
                        double *Y[], double *T, double *TOUT, int *ITOL,
                        double *RTOL, double *ATOL[], int *ITASK, int *ISTATE,
                        int *IOPT, double *RWORK[], int *LRW, int *IWORK[],
                        int *LIW, void (*jex)(int, double, double[], int, 
                                              int, double [3][3], int), 
                        int *MF);
}    




void FEX (int &NEQ, double &T, double Y[], int YDOT[]);




void JEX (int &NEQ, double &T, double Y[], int &ML, int &MU, double PD[3][3], 
          int &NRPD);




int main(){

    int IOPT, IOUT, ISTATE, ITASK, ITOL, IWORK[23], LIW, LRW, MF, NEQ, ICOUNT=1;
    double ATOL[3], RTOL, RWORK[58], T, TOUT, Y[3];
    NEQ = 3;
    Y[0] = 1;
    Y[1] = 0;
    Y[2] = 0;
    T = 0;
    TOUT = 0.4;
    ITOL = 2;
    RTOL = pow(10,-4);
    ATOL[0] = pow(10,-6);
    ATOL[1] = pow(10,-10);
    ATOL[2] = pow(10,-6);
    ITASK = 1;
    ISTATE = 1;
    IOPT = 0;
    LRW = 58;
    LIW = 23;
    MF = 21;

    for (ICOUNT; ICOUNT <13; ICOUNT++)
    {
        DLSODE_(&FEX, &NEQ, &Y, &T, &TOUT, &ITOL, &RTOL, &ATOL, &ITASK, &ISTATE, 
                &IOPT, &RWORK, &LRW, &IWORK, &LIW, &JEX, &MF);
        cout<<"At t= "<<T<<" y= "<<Y[1]<<" "<<Y[2]<<" "<<Y[3]<<"\n";
    }
}




void FEX (int &NEQ, double &T, double Y[], double YDOT[]){
    YDOT[0] = -.04*Y[0] + pow(10,4)*Y[1]*Y[2];
    YDOT[2] = 3*pow(10,7)*Y[1]*Y[1];
    YDOT[1] = -YDOT[0] - YDOT[2];
}




void JEX (int &NEQ, double &T, double Y[], int &ML, int &MU, double &PD[3][3], 
          int &NRPD){
    PD[0][0] = -.04;
    PD[0][1] = 1*pow(10,4)*Y[2];
    PD[0][2] = 1*pow(10,4)*Y[1];
    PD[1][0] = .04;
    PD[1][2] = -PD[0][2];
    PD[2][1] = 6*pow(10,7)*Y[1];
    PD[1][1] = -PD[0][1] - PD[2][1];
}
```

An the error message is

```
 cversion1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
 cversion1.cpp:44:52: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(int&, double&, double*, int*)’ to ‘void (*)(int, double, double*, double*)’
 cversion1.cpp:44:52: error: cannot convert ‘double (*)[3]’ to ‘double**’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘void DLSODE_(void (*)(int, double, double*, double*), int*, double**, double*, double*, int*, double*, double**, int*, int*, int*, double**, int*, int**, int*, void (*)(int, double, double*, int, int, double (*)[3], int), int*)’
 cversion1.cpp: At global scope:
 cversion1.cpp:55:77: error: declaration of ‘PD’ as array of references
 cversion1.cpp:55:78: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
 cversion1.cpp:56:4: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
```

Thank you,

Comment: It would be really helpful if you added comments with the line numbers in the error message, since otherwise we have to figure them out ourselves, which is a pain.

Answer (score 4):

The modern way to interface C or C++ to Fortran is to use the Fortran ISO C Binding.  This provides way to interface Fortran and C (and C++ via 'extern "C"') that is part of the Fortran language standard and is therefore compiler and platform independent.   Statements such as "Fortran passes by reference" and that Fortran compilers append underscores (made in in the webpage linked in the other answer) are no longer necessary.   The programmer can specify calling conventions compatible with C and the precise names.  This is if you are allowed to modify the Fortran code.  Or you can write a glue routine in Fortran between the C/C++ routine and the original Fortran routine.  There are many previous questions/answers on Stackoverflow about the ISO C Binding.   There are examples in the gfortran manual.

Answer (score 3):

```
void (*fex)(int, double, double[], double[])
```

does not match

```
void FEX (int &NEQ, double &T, double Y[], double YDOT[])
```

You've declared argument 3 of `DLSODE` to be `double *Y[]`, an array of pointers to `double`, but this should just be `double Y[]`.  You're passing in `&Y`, and `Y` is declared as `double Y[3]`, but you should just pass in `Y`.

In your `JEX` declaration, you have `double &PD[3][3]`, but you just want `double PD[3][3]` here.

You should express calculations like `3*pow(10,7)` as `30000000` or `3E7`, which are compile-time constants.

Also keep in mind that C and C++ use row-major order for 2-d arrays, but FORTRAN uses column-major order.  This will have the effect of transposing arrays when you pass them across the C/FORTRAN boundary.

That covers the error messages you've posted and all the errors I've seen.

Also, [this](http://wwwcompass.cern.ch/compass/software/offline/software/fandc/fandc.html) seems like a good reference for what you're trying to do.